# WiFiESP constantly losing connection

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, softwareserial, web-server

I am working on a traffic light with a ESP8266-01 wifi module on an Arduino.
The wifi card should act as a server and wait for a request to come in at `/R` (red), `/Y` (yellow), `/G` (green) or `/O` (off) and open the relay for that light.
The Arduino with wifi starts perfectly, and I can switch to a color.. but after a short while it dies and doesn't respond to requests. Sometimes after uploading a few times it seems to get the `>>> TIMEOUT >>>`, but that usually is resolved by turning of the power to the Arduino for a short while.

The ESP is set to 9600 baud and uses pins 9 and 10. Ping 6, 7 and 8 go to the relay shield for turning off/on the lights.

What is it I am missing here:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "WiFiEsp.h"

#define PINGREEN 6
#define PINYELLOW 7
#define PINRED 8

#define OFF HIGH
#define ON LOW

// WIFI Settings
char ssid[] = "somewifi";
char pass[] = "somepass";
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

// Serial settings
SoftwareSerial Serial1(9, 10);

// WiFi settings
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xDA, 0x0D, 0x14, 0xBF }; // WIFI Sheild MAC address
int reqCount = 0;                                    // number of requests received

// NETWORK: Static IP details...
IPAddress ip(10, 0, 0, 223);

WiFiEspServer server(80);

// The state of the trafic light, default state should be off
enum traficLight {
  off,
  green,
  yellow,
  red
};

// The type of data that we want to extract from the page
struct TrafficLightData {
  char red[32];
  char yellow[32];
  char green[32];
};

// Set the default of the trafic light
traficLight currentLight = off;

// use a ring buffer to increase speed and reduce memory allocation
RingBuffer buf(8);

// Change the active light of the trafic light
void changeLightTo(traficLight light, int setDelay = 1000) {
  // Start with turning all lights off
  digitalWrite(PINGREEN, OFF);
  digitalWrite(PINYELLOW, OFF);
  digitalWrite(PINRED, OFF);

  // Check if the new light requested is not off
  if (light != off) {
    int pin;
    switch (light) {
      case green:
        pin = PINGREEN;
        break;
      case yellow:
        pin = PINYELLOW;
        break;
      case red:
        pin = PINRED;
        break;
      default:
        pin = -1;
        break;
    }

    if (pin > 0) {
      digitalWrite(pin, ON);
    }
    currentLight = light;
  } else {
    currentLight = off;
  }

  if (setDelay > 0) {
    delay(setDelay);
  }
}

// Test if all the lights work
void doLightTest() {
  // Turn all lights on for 2 sec
  changeLightTo(off);

  delay(500);

  digitalWrite(PINGREEN, ON);
  digitalWrite(PINYELLOW, ON);
  digitalWrite(PINRED, ON);

  delay(1000);

  changeLightTo(off);
}

void setup() {
  // start the serial library:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(9600);

  // Setup pins
  pinMode(PINGREEN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PINYELLOW, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PINRED, OUTPUT);

  // Start with light test
  doLightTest();

  setupWifi();

  // Set the pins
  Serial.println("Settings pins:");
  Serial.print(" - GREEN: ");
  Serial.println(PINGREEN);
  Serial.print(" - YELLOW: ");
  Serial.println(PINYELLOW);
  Serial.print(" - RED: ");
  Serial.println(PINRED);

  delay(1000);

  changeLightTo(off, 0);
}

void setupWifi() {
  Serial.println("Starting wifi...");

  WiFi.init(&Serial1);
  //WiFi.config(ip);

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    changeLightTo(red, 1000);
    Serial.println("Wifi shield not present!");

    // Don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attemting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  }

  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  printWifiStatus();

  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiEspClient client = server.available();

  if (client) {
    Serial.println("New client");
    buf.init();

    while (client.connected()) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.write(c);
      buf.push(c);

      if (buf.endsWith("\r\n\r\n")) {
        sendHttpResponse(client);
        break;
      }

      if (buf.endsWith("GET /R")) {
        Serial.println("LIGHT RED!");
        changeLightTo(red, 0);
      } else if (buf.endsWith("GET /Y")) {
        Serial.println("LIGHT YELLOW!");
        changeLightTo(yellow, 0);
      } else if (buf.endsWith("GET /G")) {
        Serial.println("LIGHT GREEN!");
        changeLightTo(green, 0);
      } else if (buf.endsWith("GET /O")) {
        Serial.println("LIGHT OFF!");
        changeLightTo(off, 0);
      }
    }

    // Give the browser time to recieve the data
    delay(10);

    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");
  }

  /*if (WiFi.status() == WL_DISCONNECTED || WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECT_FAILED) {
    setupWifi();
  }*/
}

void sendHttpResponse(WiFiEspClient client) {
  Serial.println("Sending response");

  client.print(
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
    "Connection: close\r\n"
    "\r\n");
  client.print("<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n");
  client.print("<html>\r\n");
  client.print("<head>\r\n");
  client.print("<title>Traffic light</title>\r\n");
  client.print("</head>\r\n");
  client.print("<body>\r\n");
  client.print("<h1>Main page for traffic light!</h1>\r\n");
  client.print("<p>Select light to use:</p>\r\n");
  client.print("<p> - <a href='/R'>Red</a></p>\r\n");
  client.print("<p> - <a href='/Y'>Yellow</a></p>\r\n");
  client.print("<p> - <a href='/G'>Green</a></p>\r\n");
  client.print("<p> - <a href='/O'>Off</a></p>\r\n");
  client.print("</body>\r\n");
  client.print("</html>\r\n");
  client.print("\r\n");
}

void printWifiStatus() {
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // Print the IP Address
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.print(" dBm (Signal strength is ");
  Serial.print(rssiToText(rssi));
  Serial.println(")");
}

String rssiToText(float rssi) {
  if (rssi > -30) {
    return "Amazing";
  } else if (rssi > -67) {
    return "Very good";
  } else if (rssi > -70) {
    return "Okay";
  } else if (rssi > -80) {
    return "Not good";
  } else if (rssi > -90) {
    return "Unusable";
  }

  return "";
}
```

The output I get is the following:

```
Starting wifi...
[WiFiEsp] Initializing ESP module
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] Initilization successful - 1.5.4
Attemting to connect to SSID: somewifi
[WiFiEsp] Connected to somewifi
You're connected to the network
SSID: somewifi
IP address: 10.0.0.145
signal strength (RSSI):-62 dBm (Signal strength is Very good)
[WiFiEsp] Server started on port 80
Settings pins:
 - GREEN: 6
 - YELLOW: 7
 - RED: 8
[WiFiEsp] New client 0
New client
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.145
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,nl;q=0.2

Sending response
[WiFiEsp] Disconnecting  0
Client disconnected
[WiFiEsp] New client 0
New client
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.145
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://10.0.0.145/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,nl;q=0.2

Sending response
[WiFiEsp] Disconnecting  0
Client disconnected
[WiFiEsp] New client 0
New client
GET /GLIGHT GREEN!
 HTTP/1.1
Host:�[WiFiEsp] TIMEOUT: 416
[WiFiEsp] >>> TIMEOUT >>>
[WiFiEsp] No tag found
Client disconnected
```

Comment: Usually just stopping after a while is a memory leak, but I can' t see anything obvious apart from you circular buffer.  Could it be the web side is writing data into the buffer faster that it can be read.  Try a 1024byte buffer?  If it isn't that could the ESP be faulty in some way, can you swap it for a different one?

Comment: Please help us to help you by replacing your code with a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: Except for the debugging `Serial.println()` I would argue it pretty much is _mcve_. Maybe its a good idea to read the question, @MarkSmith?

Comment: @Matt good idea. I've ran the Arduino with the ESP over night now with the red light turned on and it is still on. The router stil sees the ESP connected with uptime of 17h, but when connecting to the IP I get a time out.

Comment: @PaulPeelen I respectfully disagree. Does the problem go away if you remove the LED lighting code?  What about if you only send a dummy HTTP response?

Comment: Yes and no, the LED code can impose a memory issue which gets the server to not respond. However, I can't seem to find that. The LED work on their own and the HTTP works a lot longer on its own. I removed the html return body and only return a one line text, which also keeps the module responding for a longer time.